# Comparar células de 2 colunas do resultado da query e exibir apenas linhas onde a condição seja TRUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um código SQL que pega o resultado de um `WITH` e acrescenta outra coluna manualmente (essa nova coluna trata-se de um `SELECT` já dentro do `SELECT` principal).

Minha dúvida é: gostaria de, após o retorno da consulta, comparar os valores das 2 últimas colunas e exibir apenas as linhas onde `col_a > col_b`. Tentei passar essa condição no `WHERE` porém ele não reconhece a `col_b`, dá a seguinte mensagem: `Nome de coluna 'col_b' inválido`. Há alguma forma disso ser feito?

Meu código:

```
DECLARE @forecast AS NVARCHAR(6), @produto AS NVARCHAR(6);

SET @forecast = '000015';
SET @produto = '000938';

WITH temp AS (
    SELECT
        OP.CodigoOrdem AS op_id
        ,FI.Cod_Produto AS cod_prod
        ,(
            SELECT
                FCI.Quantidade
            FROM
                [DBG].[dbo].ForeCast AS FC
                INNER JOIN [DBG].[dbo].ForeCast_itens AS FCI ON FC.CodigoFC = FCI.Cod_FC
                INNER JOIN [DBG].[dbo].ProdutoFinal AS PF ON FCI.Cod_Produto = PF.CodigoProduto
            WHERE
                FCI.Quantidade <> 0 AND PF.Inativo = 0 AND FC.CodigoFC = @forecast
                AND PF.CodigoProduto = @produto
        ) AS col_a
    FROM
        [DBG].[dbo].ForeCast F
        INNER JOIN [DBG].[dbo].ForeCast_Itens FI ON F.CodigoFC = FI.Cod_FC
        INNER JOIN [DBG].[dbo].OrdemProducao OP ON OP.Cod_FC = FI.Cod_FC AND OP.Cod_Produto = FI.Cod_Produto
    WHERE
        FI.Cod_Produto = @produto
)

SELECT
    T.cod_prod AS cod_prod
    ,T.op_id AS op_id
    ,T.col_a AS col_a
    ,ISNULL((
        SELECT SUM(PD.total_programado)
        FROM [DBG_PROFAB].[dbo].programacao_dia PD 
        WHERE PD.cod_forecast = @forecast AND PD.op_pai = T.op_id
    ), '0') AS col_b
FROM temp T
--WHERE T.col_a > col_b // Linha comentada pois não funciona.
ORDER BY op_id
```

Essa query me retorna algo nesse sentido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por esse exemplo, minha intenção seria retornar apenas a última linha.

Comment: Não tentou colocar o "select" da "col_b" no "with" ?

Comment: Ou você repete todo código no where T.col_a > ISNULL((SELECT...), '0') ou joga essa query em mais um with e faz uma nova consulta em cima desse novo with ou coloca essa query em uma subconsulta ou tenta fazer o que o @Motta falou.

Comment: @Motta tentei sim, porém essa parte `AND PD.op_pai = op_id` ele não reconhece a op_id como um elemento válido para ser comparado, retorna `Nome de coluna 'op_id' inválido`.

Comment: Seria AND PD.op_pai =  OP.CodigoOrdem , creio

Comment: @Benilson rapaz essa parte de “repete todo código no where” teste aqui e parece que deu certo, hein. Sobre as outras duas sugestões, eu não sabia que dava pra fazer `WITH` dentro de outro `WITH`, vou testar, mas sobre a subconsulta, como seria? Essa eu acho que não sei fazer.

Comment: Resolvi utilizando uma vírgula após o 1º `WITH` e declarando o 2º, para depois fazer um `SELECT` final, como foi explicado nessa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18010878/19199089 Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar.

Comment: Este tópico é para que o SOPT deveria existir , solução de problema real que possa ter impacto em outros casos, bem explicado , com a tentativa , para o 10 faltou um SqlFiddle. :)